# How do you abort running the test cases if the ClassInitialize or TestInitalize fails?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am using Microsoft unit testing in Visual Studio and I don't want to run the test cases if the ClassInitialize (preconditions) fails. 
Is there a way to stop or skip to run the test cases if ClassInitialize fails? 
The same question if TestInitialize fails but for a single test case.

Test code example in C#:

```
    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        SetupTestSystem();
        if (IsTestSystemOK == false)
        {
            SetFail(); //Don't run test cases. Only highlight that ClassInitialize failed.
        }
    }

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {
        SetupForTesting();
        if (IsTestSystemOK() == false)
        {
            SetFail(); //Don't run test case, only highlight that TestInitialize failed. 
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        //If ClassInitialize or TestInitialize fails, don't run me.
    }
```

Comment: You can make a test fail with `Assert.Fail()`. Skipping - I don't know. I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: That should fail automatically. What do you mean when it fails? Does it throw exception? We are gonna need some code-snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your `SetFail()` method call with `throw new InvalidOperationException("Test Initialisation failed")`. This will fail all of the tests before they are run

Comment: Yes that could work but that will not generate a test report, right?

Comment: That will report the tests to have failed - so any reporting would treat them as individual test failures (they all just failed for the same reason)